# Add an image frame to display after the video in JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, html, png, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I would like to display a png image for a specific number of seconds after the video is completely played and then show the replay button.

I am using JW Player 6.7, we are considering upgrading to new version but it's probably not happening any time soon.

Please suggest a solution with JS Fiddle if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The key piece of code is:

```
  onComplete: function() {
    jwplayer('player').remove();
    $('#player').html("<img src='http://placehold.it/720x480'/>");
  }
```

Here is the full code:

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
  playlist: [{
    file: "http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4"
    }],
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        events: {
          onReady: function() {
            jwplayer('player').seek(632);
            this.setFullscreen(true);
          },
          onComplete: function() {
            jwplayer('player').remove();
            $('#player').html("<img src='http://placehold.it/720x480'/>");
          }
        },
      });
```

Working pen: http://codepen.io/simsketch/pen/eBwwxe

Hope this helps, good luck!